# Getting error "Connection test failed: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.127.0.0.1"

Tags: mongodb, strapi

I am trying to install Strapi with mongodb locally (windows 8.1). During the installation, I'm getting the below error:

> Connection test failed: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.127.0.0.1

Steps followed:

```
? Choose your installation type
? Choose your installation type Custom (manual settings)
? Choose your default database client
? Choose your default database client mongo
? Database name: ppdb
? Database name: ppdb
? Host: 127.0.0.1
? Host: 127.0.0.1
? +srv connection: (false) false
? +srv connection: false
? Port (It will be ignored if you enable +srv): 27017
? Port (It will be ignored if you enable +srv): 27017
? Username: ppdbuser
? Username: ppdbuser
? Password: *********
? Password: *********
? Authentication database (Maybe "admin" or blank): ppdb
? Authentication database (Maybe "admin" or blank): ppdb
? Enable SSL connection: (y/N) N
? Enable SSL connection: No
```

In mongoDB compass, the connection is working properly.

In terminal when using the command `show dbs` it is showing the database ppdb.

```
use ppdb
```

shows

> switched to db ppdb

```
db.getUsers
```

shows

```
[
    {
            "_id" : "ppdb.ppdbuser",
            "userId" : UUID("bfdaa7d9-909c-464f-b751-a6ee8631c49c"),
            "user" : "ppdbuser",
            "db" : "ppdb",
            "roles" : [
                    {
                            "role" : "dbOwner",
                            "db" : "ppdb"
                    }
            ],
            "mechanisms" : [
                    "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                    "SCRAM-SHA-256"
            ]
    }
]
```

I have started the daemon with the following command

```
mongod --auth --dbpath /data/db
```

My db password does not contain any special character.

How can I resolve this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finished the installation.

This answer may be useful for someone who encounters these errors.

During the strapi installation for the +srv field just hit enter key instead of entering false. When typed false it is taking the URI with srv. May be a bug in Strapi.

Comment: Same issue faced with strapi